# How can I filter emails sent through an SMTPAppender using Logback by hostname?

Tags: java, xml, logback

Currently, my company uses Logback to send email alerts to our teams through an SMTPAppender configured in XML.

**logback.xml:**

```
<appender name="SMTP" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
<smtpHost>host</smtpHost>
<smtpPort>port</smtpPort>
<username>username</username>
<password>password</password>
<to>email@domain.com</to>
<from>no-reply@domain.com</from>
<subject>Email Subject</subject>
<STARTTLS>false</STARTTLS>
<SSL>true</SSL>
<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
<cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
    <!-- send just ten log entries per email -->
    <bufferSize>10</bufferSize>
</cyclicBufferTracker>
**
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
   <evaluator>
      <matcher>
           <Name>hostnameMatcher</Name>
           <regex>172-[\d]{1,3}-[\d]{1,3}-[\d]{1,3}</regex>
      </matcher>
      <expression>hostnameMatcher.matches(${HOSTNAME})</expression>
   </evaluator>
   <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
   <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
</filter>
**
</appender>
```

We get certain errors emailed to us that we would like to prevent based on their hostname. Logback has an EvaluatorFilter that seems to be exactly what we'd need, but my attempts to implement (the block above between the double asterisks) it results in this output with exception:

```
    09:35:43,895 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
    09:35:43,895 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
    09:35:43,984 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
    09:35:43,986 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
    09:35:43,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    09:35:44,005 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
    09:35:44,009 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [ROLLING-FILE]
    09:35:44,015 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1807648168 - No compression will be used
    09:35:44,018 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/var/log/pdc/java/CompanyAdministration.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
    09:35:44,018 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
    09:35:44,022 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Mon Sep 26 15:03:27 MDT 2022
    09:35:44,023 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    09:35:44,026 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender]
    09:35:44,029 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SMTP]
    09:35:44,032 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator] for [evaluator] property
    09:35:44,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.Matcher] for [matcher] property
    Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
    Reported exception:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/commons/compiler/MultiCookable
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluatorBase.start(JaninoEventEvaluatorBase.java:57)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.end(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:161)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

According to the output, it looks seems like the issue is with that EvaluatorFilter during creation, which makes me think perhaps I'm not using it correctly.

We use Spring for our backend, which should include all of the Logback dependencies I should need.

Unfortunately, all of my extensive Google search skills have been exhausted and I can't seem to get this to work. Ultimately, I'm just looking to not send emails from hostname 172.x.x.x. I'd prefer to keep the configuration inside xml, but will write a java class if I can get help figuring out how to implement it that way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think your expression need  using quotation mark with string. like this :<expression>hostnameMatcher.matches("${HOSTNAME}")</expression>.if not work ,please set debug=true to show logback debug log.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to stem from the default JaninoEvaluator during instantiation. I couldn't resolve that, so I decided to go the way of implementing a custom evaluator class and it is correctly filtering as I'd like it. Below is my implementation:

**HostnameFilter.java:**

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.EvaluationException;
import ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.EventEvaluatorBase;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class HostnameFilter extends EventEvaluatorBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(ILoggingEvent loggingEvent) throws NullPointerException, EvaluationException {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().contains("172-");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the logback.xml file, I keep the same structure, but specify my custom class inside the evaluator tag.

**logback.xml:**

```
<appender name="SMTP" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="com.my.custom.HostnameFilter"/>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <smtpHost>host</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>port</smtpPort>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <to>email@domain.com</to>
    <from>no-reply@domain.com</from>
    <subject>subject</subject>
    <STARTTLS>false</STARTTLS>
    <SSL>true</SSL>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
    <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
        <!-- send just ten log entries per email -->
        <bufferSize>10</bufferSize>
    </cyclicBufferTracker>
</appender>
```

And that's pretty much it. There's no need to include the janino dependency in the pom. Doing it this way will also allow us to easily filter email events based on different criteria as well. Hope this helps others with a similar issue.